# Estimation of cutting torque for circular saw device

Tags: materials, tools, cutting

How could I estimate the required torque for cutting through wood using a blade, say 180 mm in diameter?

I am not too sure how to approach this.

Comment: a google search for cutting forces for wood gives: http://www.woodresearch.sk/wr/201702/11.pdf

Comment: Hi. Yes I've seen this. I am looking for something much simpler then the detailed calculation. Some sort of estimation technique perhaps based on the shear strength of wood and the cutting blade. This is for estimation purposes

Comment: Have you searched the blade catalog? To get a estimation you need to know details about the wood, the blade, and the operation speed (how fast and how much you want to cut). If you're thinking about creating a DIY cutter a good reference will be get the especifications of any real complete machine (motor power, saw diameter, cuting capacity). BTW justo so you know, different places contain different wood. (Pine/construction wood here in Brazil, is much different to construction wood in other places).